# Eval Smarty Code inside a Smarty Template

Tags: smarty

is there a way to evaluate Smarty Code inside an existing Smarty template? For example, I may have the following construct:

smartyTemplate.tpl

```
<body>
  <div id="dynamicPart">
     {$valueFromDatabase}
  </div>
</body>
```

Whereas the Smarty variable $valueFromDatabase contains another Smarty Template which I would like to be inserted in place of the variable and then evaluated as a template (with all the logic expressions in replacements neccessary).

Answer (score 1):

without a custom resource, you could have just used an {include file="your/template.tpl"}.  Or render the template from the database in code using $smarty->fetch("your/template.tpl") and assigning that to $valueFromDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

```
{eval var=$valueFromDatabase}
```

will work